# Como funciona o "this" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de entender melhor como o `this` funcionado no JavaScript.

- O que ele é ?
- Quais são suas funções na linguagem ?
- E como funciona seu escopo no código ?

Comment: Ops, não tinha intenção de fechar unilateralmente... Se alguém discorda que seja duplicata, favor votar pra reabrir.

Comment: Concordo que é dup @mgibsonbr, apesar de boa pergunta. E boa resposta lá na outra pergunta.

Comment: O bom é que essa aqui acho que está melhor pra indexação para  ajudar a localizar aquela, no caso de quem busca o this especificamente. +1

Comment: @Bacco Concordo Plenamente, se fosse para pesquisar este seria o titulo da pesquisa.

Comment: @Highlander as duplicatas tem lugar especial aqui no SOpt justo por isso. Elas tem valor como índice.