# Para que serve o paramêtro THIS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Algo que sempre vejo em muitos código por aí é o paramêtro `this`.

Ex:

```
$(this).funçao-variável...
```

Já me disseram que o `this` serve para "referenciar" algo. Mas, não ficou muito claro.

Alguém sabe qual a utilidade/para que serve o `this`?

Comment: Calma ai, `this` do jquery ou aquele outro de outras linguaguens?

Comment: Agora sim, antes não tinha linguagem, então a duplicata era completamente válida.

Comment: Relacionadas: [Como funciona o “this” em JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102683/91) e [Qual a diferença entre $this e $\(this\) e this?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37770/91)

Comment: O `this` (aqui), referencia o escopo do elemento a qual você está acessando no momento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No JQuery, o $(this) faz referência ao elemento que você está utilizando no momento.

Exemplificando, se você criou uma função *blur* do JQuery para um determinado campo de texto, ao invés de ter que fazer referência ao campo toda vez que for usá-lo, você pode simplesmente usar o $(this) dentro do contexto do elemento.

```
$('#field').blur(function(){
    var field_value = $(this).val(); // $(this).val() se refere ao valor de $('#field')
    alert(field_value);
});
```

Espero que agora tenha ficado claro.

Answer (score 2):

Este [artigo](http://codigosimples.net/2016/02/21/saiba-mais-sobre-o-this-javascript/) do CódigoSimples explica muito bem o uso da terminologia.

Toda função JavaScript, ao ser executada, gera uma associação do objeto criado pelo interpretador através da palavra reservada this. A especificação da ECMAScript chama isso de ThisBinding, um evento que acontece toda vez que um código JavaScript é executado e um novo contexto de execução é estabelecido. O valor do this é constante e ele existe enquanto este contexto de execução existir.

Leia mais em  [Saiba mais sobre o “this” utilizado javascript](http://codigosimples.net/2016/02/21/saiba-mais-sobre-o-this-javascript/)

Espero ter ajudado.