# Alterando title de div

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de alterar dinamicamente via jQuery o `title` de uma `div`.

Estou com o código abaixo, porém não funciona. Ele faz o post, retorna o valor correto. Porém, com o mouse em cima da `div` referida, o `title` não é alterado.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
    $(document).on('hover','.buscar_detalhes',function(){
        var codigo = $(this).attr('codigo');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {codigo : codigo},
            url: "buscar_detalhes.php",
            success: function(resposta){
                $(this).attr('title',resposta);
                $(this).prop('title',resposta);
            }
        });
    });

<div codigo='123' class='buscar_detalhes'>VER DETALHES</div>
```

Comment: Me parece que o `$('this')` dentro da sua função `success`, não é sua `<div>`, você pode colocar fora do ajax um `var self = $('this')` e usar essa variavel `self` dentro da função `success`

Comment: Talvez essa resposta possa ajudar, de uma olhada em **Alguns problemas comuns com o `this`** -- [Ao tentar criar um objeto usando `this` o console diz que a propriedade é undefined](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/381530/3774)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não use o evento `hover`. Ele foi removido do jQuery a partir da versão 1.9, e mesmo que você esteja usando uma versão compatível (até 1.8), utilize `mouseover` (ou `mouseenter`):

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.buscar_detalhes',function(){...
```

O uso do `hover` como evento pode causar efeitos indesejados, segundo consta **[neste documento](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11731)**<sup>1</sup>, e seu uso não é recomendado, mesmo se estiver usando uma versão compatível.

Outro erro, como já comentado, é que o `$(this)` dentro do Ajax faz referência ao próprio Ajax, e não ao elemento que disparou o evento.

Com isso você teria que declarar uma variável referenciando o elemento fora do Ajax, por exemplo:

```
var $el = $(this);
```

E usar essa variável dentro do Ajax:

```
$el.attr('title',resposta);
```

> Você pode dar qualquer nome à variável, até mesmo sem o `$`. O uso do
>   `$` antes da variável é apenas para saber que se trata de um objeto
>   jQuery. Mas poderia ser também:
>
> ```
> var el = $(this);
> ```

O código ficaria:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.buscar_detalhes',function(){
   var $el = $(this);
   var codigo = $el.attr('codigo');
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      data: {codigo : codigo},
      url: "buscar_detalhes.php",
      success: function(resposta){
         $el.attr('title',resposta);
      }
   });
});
```

---

<sup>**<sup>1</sup>** Agradecimentos à ajuda do amigo [@Julio Cesar Hintze dos Santos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/114438/julio-cesar-hintze-dos-santos) nos comentários.</sup>

Comment: De acordo com o op, o post é executado. Isso significa que a versão do jQuery dele ainda funciona o evento "hover" usando a função .on(). Na versão mais recente do jQuery isso já não é mais possível (apenas usando .hover ()). O único problema do código dele é o "this" dentro da função success mesmo

Comment: O jQuery usa eventos globais do JavaScript. Nenhuma documentação mostra que `hover` é um evento. No jQuery o `.hover()` é um método e não um evento.

Comment: Se ele diz que está fazendo o post, creio que ele esteja equivocado. :D

Comment: Era possível usar o pseudo-evento hover no jQuery até a versão 1.9. Na versão 1.8 ele foi depreciado e na 1.9 foi removido. Fontes: https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/ https://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.9/

Comment: É verdade. O jQuery estava tratando o hover como evento, mas, como mostra o documento que vc me enviou no link, ele foi removido na versão 1.9 porque viram que não era uma boa rs. Valeu aí e já atualizei a resposta com essa informação.

Comment: Coloquei os créditos da informação no final da resposta ;)

Answer (score 0):

Na função success, veja se o `this` é realmente o objeto que você quer alterar o title. Caso não seja, você pode declarar uma variável logo acima do `$.ajax`, como `var $el = $(this);`, e dentro da função success você faz referência à ela: `$el.attr('title', resposta);`