# Acesso ao 'this' em diferentes tipos de funções anonimas

Tags: javascript

A questão é simples, porque quando eu faço isso:

```js
function reducer(accumulator, current) {
    return accumulator.concat(current);
}

Array.prototype.flatMap = () => {
  return this.reduce(reducer, []);
};
```

É lançada a exceção: `this.reduce is not a function`, porém, quando eu mudo para:

```js
function reducer(accumulator, current) {
    return accumulator.concat(current);
}

Array.prototype.flatMap = function () {
  return this.reduce(reducer, []);
};
```

Tudo funciona normalmente.

O que eu imagino que deveria acontecer é: Ao passar a função para o prototype do Array, ele deveria bindar a função automaticamente, independente se ela é anônima ou não. E pelo visto isso não acontece.

O que eu não entendo é que já que ambas são funções anônimas, ambas deveriam herdar o `this` do escopo pai, mas por algum motivo somente a primeira está herdando, já segunda não, o `this` dela é o próprio array, porque? O bind da primeira função não deveria ser igual o da segunda?

Comment: A tua função tem o nome de "reducer" e você está chamando "this.reduce" (sem o R no fim). Não faz diferença no teu código?

Comment: Não, `this.reduce` é o reduce do Array.prototype.reduce, reducer é uma função minha.

Comment: Relacionada: [Ao tentar criar um objeto usando `this` o console diz que a propriedade é undefined](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/381442/3774)