# Para que serve o método Function.prototype.call()?

Tags: javascript, funções

Eu fico confuso em utilizar o método `call()`. Ele serve para chamar uma função, herdar os parâmetros de uma função ou as propriedades?

Outra dúvida minha é em relação a palavra-chave `this` passada como parâmetro para o método `call()`, por exemplo:

```js
function A (n1, n2, n3) {
   this.n1 = n1;
   this.n2 = n2;
   this.n3 = n3;

   this.numbers = () => {
       console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3}`)
   };
}

function B (n1, n2, n3) {
   A.call(this, n1, n2, n3);

   this.numbers = () => {
       console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3}`);
   };
}

let a1 = new A(10, 20, 30);
let b1 = new B(100, 200, 300);

console.log(a1.numbers());
console.log(b1.numbers());
```

A palavra-chave `this` que está dentro do método `call()` está se referindo a quêm? Ao construtor `A` ou `B`? E por que ela deve estar alí passada como parâmetro? Eu falo isso porque o [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) menciona que o uso dela é opcional no método `call()`.

No primeiro exemplo é usado o `this` como parâmetro do método `call()`, mas neste segundo exemplo não:

```js
function A (n1, n2, n3) {
   this.n1 = n1;
   this.n2 = n2;
   this.n3 = n3;

   this.numbers = () => {
       console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3}`)
   };
}

function B (n1, n2, n3) {
   A.call(n1, n2, n3);

   this.numbers = () => {
       console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3}`);
   };
}

let a1 = new A(10, 20, 30);
let b1 = new B(100, 200, 300);

console.log(a1.numbers());
console.log(b1.numbers());
```

Então tanto faz usar ela, visto que os mesmos resultados serão retornados? Que efeito isso vai causar em usar e não usar?

Comment: Relacionado: [Ao tentar criar um objeto usando `this` o console diz que a propriedade é undefined](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/381530/3774)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em JavaScript, o `this` é bem dinâmico, [variando conforme o contexto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). E [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) é uma das maneiras de se controlar isso. Por exemplo, se eu tiver uma função que retorna `this`:

```js
function bla() {
    return this;
}

console.log(bla());

// se rodar no snippet do site, como é em um browser, o this é igual a window
console.log(bla() == window); // true
```

Se não estiver em modo *strict* (no qual `this` é `undefined`), a função retorna o objeto global (`window`, se estiver no browser).

Mas usando `call`, podemos alterar o `this` que a função enxerga:

```js
function bla() {
    return this;
}

let sereiUmNovoThis = { id: 1, nome: 'Novo this' };
console.log(bla.call(sereiUmNovoThis)); // { id: 1, nome: 'Novo this' }

//---------------------------------------------
// exemplo com parâmetro
function imprimeProp(propName) {
    console.log(this[propName]);
}

imprimeProp.call({ id: 1 }, 'id'); // 1
imprimeProp.call([1, 2, 3], 'length'); // 3
```

Repare que se a função tiver parâmetros, estes também são passados para `call`. De forma geral, ao fazer:

```
funcao.call(p0, p1, p2, p3, ..pn);
```

`p0` se torna o `this`, e os demais (de `p1` até `pn`) são passados como argumentos para a função.

Ou seja, `imprimeProp.call({ id: 1 }, 'id');` faz com que o objeto `{ id: 1 }` seja o `this`, e a string `'id'` seja o primeiro argumento da função (ou seja, `propName` neste caso terá o valor `'id'`).

No segundo caso, o array `[1, 2, 3]` é o `this` e a string `'length'` é o valor de `propName`.

---

A documentação cita [vários exemplos de uso](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Examples), então não vou ficar repetindo um a um.

Quanto ao seu exemplo, vamos modificá-lo um pouco para entender melhor o que aconteceu:

```js
function A (n1, n2, n3) {
    console.log(`recebido: ${this}, ${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3}`);
    this.v1 = n1;
    this.v2 = n2;
    this.v3 = n3;

    this.numbers = () => {
        console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3} - ${this.v1}, ${this.v2}, ${this.v3}`);
    };
}

function B (n1, n2, n3) {
    A.call(n1, n2, n3);

    this.numbers = () => {
        console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3} - ${this.v1}, ${this.v2}, ${this.v3}`);
    };
}

console.log('criando a1');
let a1 = new A(10, 20, 30);
console.log(a1);
a1.numbers();

console.log('criando b1');
let b1 = new B(100, 200, 300);
console.log(b1);
b1.numbers();
```

A saída é:

```
criando a1
recebido: [object Object], 10, 20, 30
{
  "v1": 10,
  "v2": 20,
  "v3": 30,
  "numbers": () => {
        console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3} - ${this.v1}, ${this.v2}, ${this.v3}`);
    }
}
10, 20, 30 - 10, 20, 30
criando b1
recebido: 100, 200, 300, undefined
{
  "numbers": () => {
        console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3} - ${this.v1}, ${this.v2}, ${this.v3}`);
    }
}
100, 200, 300 - undefined, undefined, undefined
```

Vamos por partes, primeiro vejamos o que acontece com `a1`:

- `new A(10, 20, 30)` chama a função `A` passando os valores 10 para `n1`, 20 para `n2` e 30 para `n3`
- esses valores são atribuídos respectivamente a `this.v1`, `this.v2` e `this.v3`
- também é criado o método `numbers`, que imprime os valores de `n1`, `n2` e `n3`, além de `this.v1`, `this.v2` e `this.v3`

No caso, os valores estão corretos, conforme o esperado. Eu imprimi o próprio `a1` e podemos ver os valores de `this.v1`, `this.v2` e `this.v3`, iguais aos que foram passados. O método `numbers` também imprimiu os valores corretamente.

Agora, o que acontece com `b1`?

- `new B(100, 200, 300)` chama a função `B` passando os valores 100 para `n1`, 200 para `n2` e 300 para `n3`
- é feita a chamada para `A.call(n1, n2, n3)`. Ou seja, `n1` é o primeiro argumento, **então nesse caso ele é o `this`** (podemos ver isso em `` console.log(`recebido: ${this}, ${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3}`) ``, veja que `this` é igual a 100). Com isso, `n1` recebeu o valor 200, `n2` recebeu 300 e `n3` ficou `undefined`.
- o método `numbers` imprime os valores de `n1`, `n2` e `n3`, mas não os valores que `A` recebeu, e sim os que `B` recebeu (pois este é definido dentro de `B`). Por isso que ele imprime `100, 200, 300` corretamente.
- mas repare que ao imprimir `b1`, não aparecem os valores de `v1`, `v2` e `v3`. Por isso ao imprimir `this.v1`, `this.v2` e `this.v3`, todos estão `undefined`

---

E se passarmos o `this` como o primeiro argumento de `call`?

```js
function A (n1, n2, n3) {
    console.log(`recebido: ${this}, ${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3}`);
    this.v1 = n1;
    this.v2 = n2;
    this.v3 = n3;

    this.numbers = () => {
        console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3} - ${this.v1}, ${this.v2}, ${this.v3}`);
    };
}

function B (n1, n2, n3) {
    A.call(this, n1, n2, n3); // passei o this como argumento

    this.numbers = () => {
        console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3} - ${this.v1}, ${this.v2}, ${this.v3}`);
    };
}

console.log('criando a1');
let a1 = new A(10, 20, 30);
console.log(a1);
a1.numbers();

console.log('criando b1');
let b1 = new B(100, 200, 300);
console.log(b1);
b1.numbers();
```

Agora a saída é:

```
criando a1
recebido: [object Object], 10, 20, 30
{
  "v1": 10,
  "v2": 20,
  "v3": 30,
  "numbers": () => {
        console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3} - ${this.v1}, ${this.v2}, ${this.v3}`);
    }
}
10, 20, 30 - 10, 20, 30
criando b1
recebido: [object Object], 100, 200, 300
{
  "v1": 100,
  "v2": 200,
  "v3": 300,
  "numbers": () => {
        console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3} - ${this.v1}, ${this.v2}, ${this.v3}`);
    }
}
100, 200, 300 - 100, 200, 300
```

Agora sim. Ao fazer `A.call(this, n1, n2, n3)`, estou passando o `this`, que no caso refere-se a `B` (já que estou dentro da função `B`). Ou seja, estou chamando `A`, mas ela considera que `B` é o `this`. Por isso os valores de `this.v1`, `this.v2` e `this.v3` são setados corretamente em `B`.

Aliás, isso é exatamente o [primeiro exemplo da documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Using_call_to_chain_constructors_for_an_object). É uma forma de `B` "reaproveitar" a função construtora `A`. Aliás, como agora estamos passando o `this` correto, a função `B` nem precisaria redefinir `numbers` (pois este já seria criado corretamente dentro de `A`):

```js
function A (n1, n2, n3) {
    console.log(`recebido: ${this}, ${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3}`)
    this.v1 = n1;
    this.v2 = n2;
    this.v3 = n3;

    this.numbers = () => {
        console.log(`${n1}, ${n2}, ${n3} - ${this.v1}, ${this.v2}, ${this.v3}`);
    };
}

function B (n1, n2, n3) {
    A.call(this, n1, n2, n3);
}

let b = new B(1, 2, 3);
b.numbers();
```

Como eu passei `this` para `A` (e este é `B`), então `this.numbers` define `numbers` em `B`, e tudo funciona como o esperado.

Talvez o que mais confunda neste caso é o fato do `this` significar uma coisa diferente a cada momento.

[image]

---

Quanto ao primeiro argumento ser opcional, a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call#Using_call_to_invoke_a_function_and_without_specifying_the_first_argument) cita que de fato é, mas aí você não pode passar nenhum outro argumento (teria que ser apenas `A.call()`). Neste caso, o `this` passa a ser o objeto global (ou `undefined` se estiver no modo *strict*).

```js
function bla() {
    return this;
}

// se rodar no snippet do site, como é em um browser, o this é igual a window
console.log(bla.call() == window); // true

function blaStrict() {
    "use strict";
    return this;
}

console.log(blaStrict.call()); // undefined
```

---

Não é algo diretamente relacionado à pergunta, mas na verdade, da forma que você fez, uma nova função `numbers` sempre é criada cada vez que você cria um novo `A` ou `B`. O ideal seria declarar a função no `prototype` de `A`, ou usar a [sintaxe de classes do ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Como não é o foco da pergunta, deixo algumas referências: [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript), [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/112052), [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108548/112052) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90290/112052).

Comment: Muito boa resposta, obrigado mesmo ajudou muito em esclarecer minhas dúvidas :).

Answer (score 4):

Você só precisa usar o `call` se quiser redefinir a qual objeto um método está vinculado para aquela execução.

O `this` em js é dinâmico. Sendo assim você pode transferir métodos entre objetos e tudo funciona.

O `call` te permite executar um método no contexto de um objeto, sem precisar vincular esse método ao objeto. Esse exemplo deve esclarecer:

```js
let A = {
  x: 2,
  dobro() {
    return this.x * 2
  }
};

let B = {
  x: 3
};

let C = {
  x: 4
};

B.dobro = A.dobro;

console.log('Dobro of B.x:', B.dobro());
console.log('Dobro of C.x:', A.dobro.call(C));

console.log('Attributes of B:', Object.keys(B));
console.log('Attributes of C:', Object.keys(C));
```

Como você pode ver, o dobro é apresentado corretamente para os objetos B e C, mas o C não incorporou o método. Isso previne poluição de objetos ou permite meta-programação de formas mais elaboradas.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro para mim colega dos pontos mencionados na pergunta, se possível reforçar mais detalhes na responta, agradeço!