# Dentro de um método pertencente a um objeto, o this da função chamada não aponta para o objeto

Tags: javascript, node.js, funções

Eu tenho uma função:

```
let comparaComThis = function (param) {
    console.log (this === param)
}
```

E tenho um objeto que chama essa função:

```
const obj2 = {  
    consta(){ 
        comparaComThis(obj2)
    }
}
```

A questão é que quando eu chamo a função do objeto, o `this` aponta para o global. Por quê?

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context):

> *Inside a function (...) `this` will default to the global object.*

Ou seja, o código abaixo (rodando em um browser) imprimirá "true":

```js
function f() {
    // no browser, this é igual a window
    console.log(this == window);

    // no Node, this é igual ao objeto global
    //console.log(this == globalThis);
}

f();
```

E neste caso não importa onde a função é chamada, o `this` dela continua sendo o mesmo:

```js
function f() {
    console.log('dentro de f =', this === window);
}

let obj = {
    chama_f() {
        console.log('dentro de obj.chama_f =', this === obj);
        f();
    }
};

obj.chama_f();
```

A saída deste código é:

```
dentro de obj.chama_f = true
dentro de f = true
```

Ou seja, dentro da função `chama_f`, o `this` é igual a `obj`, mas dentro da função `f`, o `this` continua sendo o `window`. Mesmo que `f` tenha sido chamada dentro de `chama_f`, não importa, o `this` dela não é afetado pelo `this` de quem a chamou.

---

É isso que está acontecendo no seu caso. Dentro da função `consta`, o `this` refere-se a `obj2`, mas dentro de `comparaComThis`, o `this` é o `window`.

```js
let comparaComThis = function (param) {
    console.log('comparaComThis =', this === window);
}

const obj2 = {  
    consta(){
        console.log('consta =', this === obj2);
        comparaComThis(obj2);
    }
};
obj2.consta();
```

A saída do código acima é:

```
consta = true
comparaComThis = true
```

---

Se quer mudar o `this` que `comparaComThis` enxerga, uma alternativa é usar [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) (que é explicado em mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/462870/112052)):

```js
let comparaComThis = function (param) {
    console.log('comparaComThis =', this === param);
}

const obj2 = {  
    consta(){
        // aqui o "this" é obj2, e com call() eu informo que também será o "this" da função comparaComThis
        console.log('consta =', this === obj2);
        comparaComThis.call(this, obj2);
    }
};
obj2.consta();
```

O primeiro argumento de `call` é o objeto que será visto como `this` dentro de `comparaComThis`. No caso, eu passei o `this` referente à função `consta`, que já vimos no exemplo anterior que é `obj2`. E do segundo argumento em diante é o que será passado para a função `comparaComThis` (no caso, eu passei `obj2`, ou seja, dentro da função, `param` será `obj2`).

---

Sim, é confuso. Mas é assim que o `this` funciona, cada hora ele pode ser uma coisa diferente...

[image]

---

E não diretamente relacionado, mas nesse caso você também poderia declarar a função como:

```
function comparaComThis(param) {
    etc...
}
```

Neste caso não há ganho nenhum em usar uma *function expression*, mas como é um exemplo simples, também não faz diferença. Mas há casos em que faz, saiba mais [lendo aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/112052).

Comment: Mas nesse caso em específico, no meu,como não é Arrow, o this mesmo assim não muda pelo contexto de chamada?

Comment: @Arthur Mas eu mostrei que o `this` muda. Dentro de `consta`, o `this` é igual a `obj2`, e dentro de `comparaComThis`, o `this` é o objeto global (`window` se rodar em um browser, `globalThis` se rodar no Node). Não entendi o que vc não entendeu :-)

Answer (score 0):

Este é o comportamento padrão da linguagem. O this se comporta diferente no js do que em outras linguagens.

Segue um bom link explicando as diferenças: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Vi o link e não achei nenhum topico em que ele aborda o mesmo caso que o meu